# Variables in django-user-accounts ( pinax )

Tags: django, pinax

In the pinax project, how someone can configure the variables (like, {{ current_site }}, {{ email_url }}, {{ activate_url }} etc. ) in order to adapt the django-user-accounts, pinax app?

For example, when I configure my settings.py and set

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED = True
```

Now, when I create a new user I get the message

```
Confirm your email address

We have sent you an email to e@e.com for verification. 
Follow the    link provided to finalize the signup process. 
If you do not receive it within a few minutes, contact us 
at support@example.com
```

So my question is, where are these Django variables and how can I change them in order support@example.com changes to the desired email address?

Comment: I've never used pinax but a quick google search shows customizing that variable depends on the theme you're using. Take a look at https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-classic/blob/master/pinax_theme_classic/templates/account/verification_sent.html#L10 and https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap-account/blob/master/pinax_theme_bootstrap_account/templates/account/email_confirmation_sent.html#L11

Answer (score 0):

Add in your settings.py

```
THEME_CONTACT_EMAIL = 'desired@email.com'
```